# In Ansible, how can I fetch file from multiple nodes and store this in one file centralized?

Tags: file, ansible, fetch, clients

All what I need is in title, for example I want to know how I can do somethings like that :

```
---
- hosts: ansible-clients

  tasks:
    - name: Fetch source list from clients
      fetch: src=/etc/apt/sources.list
             dest=/tmp/allnodes.sourcelist
```

OR in simply way

```
echo remote@/etc/apt/sources.list >> local@/tmp/allnodes.sourcelist
```

I can create and run script in local but the only condition I have is to do all actions in one playbook.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this play:

```
---
- hosts: ansible-clients
  tasks:
    - name: Fetch source list from clients
      fetch:
        src: /etc/apt/sources.list
        flat: yes
        dest: "/tmp/{{ inventory_hostname }}.sourcelist"
    - name: Merge files
      run_once: yes
      delegate_to: localhost
      shell: "cat /tmp/{{ item }}.sourcelist >> /tmp/allnodes.sourcelist"
      with_items: "{{ groups['ansible-clients'] }}"
```

- First task is used to fetch all files from remotes and store them in `/tmp`. `inventory_hostname` is used in filename to be sure it is unique.
- Second task is run once on any host, and append all files (get list of hosts linked to group ansible-clients) in final file

Comment: `run_once` limits the job count to 1, but that will still run on a remote host. You have to add `delegate_to: localhost` to concat the files locally.

Comment: I will try your playbook and I come back. Thanks :)

Comment: It works fine !! Gracias me amigo Nelson ;)

This is what I like on stackoverflow